# Mysql query is too slow when order by datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing

I have a table with about 10k rows. I run below sql but it's take too much time (~4 seconds):

```
SELECT
        ID, post_date, post_title, post_name, pc.post_view,
        t.name AS post_category,
        pm2.meta_value AS post_image
    FROM wp_posts p
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy='category'
        INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id AND (t.name='My Posts' OR t.name='HOT posts')
        LEFT JOIN post_counter pc ON p.ID = pc.post_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON pm.meta_value = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'post'
    ORDER BY FIELD(t.name, 'HOT posts', 'My Posts'), post_date DESC
    LIMIT 14
```

If I remove "order by post_date", everything fine. It's take only 0.05 second to run.

I added some indexes with CREATE INDEX and ADD INDEX (I don't know what's difference between them):

```
CREATE INDEX ix_type_date ON wp_posts (post_type, post_date)

ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX ix_status_type_date (post_status,post_type,post_date)
```

Then use these indexes with USE INDEX and FORCE INDEX (I also don't know what's difference between them):

```
    ...FROM wp_posts p USE INDEX (ix_type_date)...
```

OR

```
    ...FROM wp_posts p FORCE INDEX (ix_status_type_date)...
```

I still get my records, but loading time increased to 7-8 seconds.

Table's structure

```
ID  bigint(20)  No           
post_author bigint(20)  No  0        
post_date   datetime    No  0000-00-00 00:00:00          
post_date_gmt   datetime    No  0000-00-00 00:00:00          
post_content    longtext    No           
post_title  text    No           
post_excerpt    text    No           
post_status varchar(20) No  publish          
comment_status  varchar(20) No  open         
ping_status varchar(20) No  open         
post_password   varchar(255)    No           
post_name   varchar(200)    No           
to_ping text    No           
pinged  text    No           
post_modified   datetime    No  0000-00-00 00:00:00          
post_modified_gmt   datetime    No  0000-00-00 00:00:00          
post_content_filtered   longtext    No           
post_parent bigint(20)  No  0        
guid    varchar(255)    No           
menu_order  int(11) No  0        
post_type   varchar(20) No  post         
post_mime_type  varchar(100)    No           
comment_count   bigint(20)  No  0
```

Comment: Can you post table structure here with index?

Comment: Can you try putting a composite index on `wp_terms.name` and `post_date` ?

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements for ALL relevant tables, as well as the results of the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Sorry, I'm still a newbie. I don't know how create an index from two tables. Can you tell me more clearly?

Comment: @phong I think first you should set default value of date field is null that is essential it may impact on performance

Comment: @Dipakchavda: It's a Wordpress database. Everything is created automatically when I upload wordpress to my server. I can't change anything on them.

Answer (score 0):

You want "Hot posts" first, then "my posts"?  And there are likely to be fewer than 14 Hotties, and there are lots of "my posts"?

One clumsy solution is to

```
( SELECT ... name='HOT posts' ORDER BY post_date DESC  LIMIT 14 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... name='My Posts'  ORDER BY post_date DESC  LIMIT 14 )
ORDER BY field(...), post_date DESC  LIMIT 14
```

Note that there is some chance of quickly finding the latest 14 of each category, then quickly rearranging the 28 to get the desired 14.

For many-to-many tables, see [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) for how to improve their performance.  (The default WP is rather inefficient.)

If you need to discuss further, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.